Account suspension for excessive editing: What's an acceptable number of edits within a given timeframe?
A moderator just suspended my Math SE account for 7 days because of excessive editing of one of my posts (edit history), while I edited the post only three times today (August 22, 2024). The last one was only correcting a link. I have not edited the post for 18 days.
I have been suspended twice for excessive editing once on Jul 31, 2024 and once on August 22, 2024. I edited the above post 5 more times over 22 days after my last suspension, and again I was suspended (two of correctios were very minor edits).
I believe this can be repeated again and I do not know how much I should edit a post so that the moderator will not suspend my account again. You can see the current answer by @Starship have been edited 6 times within two hours while my account was suspended again for 5 extra edits over 22 days after my last suspension. It is why I need a clear answer to the following question (note that my account suspended for a specific post given above, not the whole number of my edits to all of my 200+25 posts, my edit rate is 5.3):

What is the maximum number of times (and over what period) that one can edit a post, without drawing moderator action?

Is it three times a day? Less? More?
I could not find any guidelines on this topic anywhere, especially as a reason of account suspension, which signals members stop caring too much about their posts.
If it is so important, why it is not mentioned anywhere or controlled automatically by restricting the number of edits per day for each post (which is a simple task for the IT section).

Here is the private message I received with the suspension:

Hello,
We're writing in reference to your Mathematics Stack Exchange account:
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1231520/amir
We noticed that you've edited https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4950857/ quite a number of times over a relatively short period of times. We have previously contacted you about excessive editing. It is disruptive to the site, and there are resources (such as the Sandbox for drafts of long, complex posts) which are meant to help you avoid making this kind of disruption.
It is absolutely fine to edit mistakes out of your posts, but we expect that the majority of the edits are done before submitting. Making multiple small edits over the course of several days is not appropriate.
Your account has been temporarily suspended for 7 days. While you're suspended, your reputation will show as 1 but will be restored once the suspension ends.
Regards,
Mathematics Stack Exchange Moderation Team

I never thought that my account would be suspended because of three times editing my post. While all of the suspension reasons listed on the site are unethical practices, suspending my account for editing a post would seriously damage my reputation because other members would not know that my account was suspended for fraud or three times editing one of my post where no guidelines limit the maximum number of revisions to a post.

A key point on the idea of bumping:

... editing an answer every day bumps that question to the front page every day

The idea of bumping by editing posts CANNOT be applied to Math SE because the front page of Math SE does not have ACTIVE tab (influenced by editing). Instead of ACTIVE tab (commonly used in other communities), Math SE replaced it by INTERESTING tab, which can be fully controlled.

Hence, editing an answer post in MSE never results in that its related question post become more visible in the front page.
I spent a considerable amount of time to produce high quality answers. If I wanted to earn more reputations I could spend less time on answering new easy questions instead of improving my old answers to difficult and controversial questions.

There is no strict rule on editing in this form. You would need to respond to the moderator message to receive more relevant information, we here can only speculate. My expectation is the editing was deemed disruptive, and that's why it lead to a suspension, not because is passed some arbitrary threshold.

If you have reason to believe the suspension was unwarranted and/or you are unfairly being targeted, please take a look at What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?. Otherwise, you should respond to the moderator private message with some form of acknowledgement and ask for them to reverse it early.

As a general observation... editing an answer every day bumps that question to the front page every day. On a site will a smaller amount of traffic, that could indeed be disruptive.

In the mod message you provided, they mention: "We have previously contacted you about excessive editing", which suggests that this is not the whole story, and that this most recent event was just the final straw, not the only reason you were suspended.

@KevinB You may see the image of the moderator's message. They did not respond. I need to know the legal rate of edits to consider it in future. It is the second time that they suspended my account for this reason. I belive that three times editing a post is not considered excessive editing.

if i'm understanding correctly, the suspension happened only a few hours ago. Mods on that stack may simply not be around or may be busy, but in either case there is no answer to be found here.

@Spevacus As I stated above for Kevin, it is the second time. They have not responded to my messages  yet. I need to know the rate to consider it personally. It can be also useful for other members. Would you consider three times editing as excessive editing? Have you ever seen before such a suspension reason in other SE sites.

I have seen suspensions for rollback wars, which is a different form of excessive editing, as well as suspensions for other forms of disruptive behavior, but not for many smaller edits to the same post absent a dispute. (this doesn't mean the the mod is in the wrong in this case, i don't know what the policies of Math.se are.) What does seem clear is you were warned of a particular type of activity, and then seem to have continued doing it. :shrug:

Imagine a heap of sand, if you remove one grain is it still a heap, two grains? At what point is it just a few grains of sand and not a heap. Fixating on some exact number is not useful.

There are a few points to make. This meta math post gives another instance, but it was not for over-editing. Secondly, there were 4 edits over 7/26, 9 over 7/30 and 7/31, and 3 on 8/22. About 9 edits added a few more words or did minor rewordeding and the rest added some more examples/work to the post. These edits can be combined together or the sandbox can be used.

Was the instance on 7/31 also for over-editing the same post?

@TymaGaidash It was on a different answer to another controversial question. Among all of my 200 answers,  only for a few of them the number of edits exceeds 20.

@TymaGaidash I tried to check all of my 225=200+25 posts one by one. The number of edits in 4 of them is greater than 20, in 6=2+4 of them is greater than 15, and 14=8+2+4 of them is grater than 10 (among all of 225 posts only for 6 of them the number of edits is greater than 15). My mean rate of edit per post is apparently less than 5.3 (1210 revisions given here also includes my edits to other members' posts.)

@KevinB As I checked, the bumping rule cannot be applied for Math SE or other similar ones such as Stack-overflow. First, you may note that Math SE and Stack-overflow replaced Active tab by Interesting tab in their front pages. Moreover, in such stacks with some amount of traffic in a few minutes hundreds of post modifications are performed. Hence, even if such stakes use Active tab, only in a few minutes almost all of posts listed under Active tab will be updated (and no one can take advantage of editing a post to make it more visible in the front page).

Please don't delete and repost comments, even if it's just to correct their grammar. It pings the other user each time you do that and gives the impression that you're harassing them for a response.

@F1Krazy Thanks! Your point is true. I just tried to fixe some errors in my last two comments that could not be fixed after 5 minutes.

It certainly gets annoying to see someone editing their answer or question 24, 30, and 45 times within a short time span. This is especially true if the edits are minor , it's easy to suspect an over zealous editor want to keep their post on the main or the active page to earn more votes (???)  Consider also the fact that users may have flagged your edited post, and as a result, moderators were forced to act.

Tip: fix all the typos, formatting, grammar in one large edit after you have identified several issues. Then leave it. Look at the post the next day with fresh eyes and improve your post where necessary, you could edit it twice but then leave it.  Let users fix any remaining errors they may find. No one will complain if a post has been edited three times in its entirety.

This question can't reasonably be answered here, because the answer really depends on norms of the specific site in question: Math.SE. From the information you've provided, and the added context that Math doesn't even have an active filter on the homepage, seems to imply that you might have been unfairly treated– but that conversation needs to occur on the site and with the community it affects, not here. Your question was closed because only Math.SE's meta & community can give you the clarification you seek, which hasn't changed.

@zcoop98 Math does have a filter for active posts.  It is not the default, but many users browse with active posts at the top.

You have bumped the post in question (since posting it) 21 different times, with many minor or completely useless edits. You have even been warned about it and suspended for it (apparently). The fact that you “only” did it 3 times today isn’t the entirety of why. The message said “several days” for a reason.
There is no maximum number of times you can edit a post per day. The only thing that will get you in trouble is having the editing being disruptive, and 21 bumps to main page likely is. Also, an average of 4 bumps per day of your posts in the time you’ve been on the site is disruptive. If today is an average day, then that would mean that the majority of the time the main page would have a least 1 of your bumped posts and a lot of the time 2 or more (over a span over 10.5 months). 1 edit vandalizing a post is bad, 1 edit significantly improving the post is certainly not.

all of the suspension reasons listed on the site are unethical practices

All of the suspension reasons on every site are to prevent disruption to the goals of said site, while allowing the user to later resume constructive contributions after the suspension expires. Regardless, everyone’s definition of “ethical” is different, and that is not how policies are made.
Disclaimer:I am not a mod on Math SE and did not have any to do with your suspension. This is just my theory.

It is not fair. I edited the post 21 times over  one month. I received many comments on my answer, some of them were deleted. Also, we had some progress in other related questions. The number of editions depends on many factors such as the difficulty of the ptlriblem, number of the comments, etc. You cannot apply a single rule to all

(As someone who’s been suspended on Math SE for this) bumping a post a lot with minor edits is a good way to get yourself suspended. It is extraordinarily difficult to make the case that you required 22 different revisions across 1 month to make a good answer…@Amir

@amir You were asked not to do something by moderators, you ignored that instruction and now you're paying the price. Don't ignore instructions from moderators in future.

@RobertLongson This answer only supports the suspension. My question is very clear What is the maximum number of times that a post can be edited. I want to consider it in the future.

@Amir I gave you the answer there is:there is no hard limit.

Were did you get such information on the number of my edits if you are not realted to the suspension: an average of 4 bumps per day of your posts in the time you’ve been on the site is disruptive. During my 310 days membership,  I answered 200 questions and asked 25 questions.

@Amir Same method as testing for ya. This info is publicly available in your user profile area.

1210/(200+25) = 5.3 is not too much considering the number of my answers and questions (200+25).

On a stack as large as Math SE that much of the main page being your posts that you bumped for 310 days consistently with minor edits is way too much.

To this moment, you edited your answer 6 times after posting it, greater than my average 5.3, while you were advising not to edit too much :-). I hope now you see why authors need to revise their posts.

@Amir however note that I bump my posts with minor edits to the main page 4 times per day. This question is scored so low it can’t even appear on the main page…as well most of my posts I don’t edit this much…besides all (but maybe 1) of those edits added significant new content…and 6 is less than 21

Sometimes I write a question, and leave it in "draft" mode for days while I re-read it and tweak it.
There have been times when I wrote a huge chunk of text that ends up being irrelevant or distracting.   So I delete that piece, before posting.  At the end of the day, the question is "better" for it.
Suggestion: take some time to "polish" your questions to the best of your ability, and then post.   That way, you're asking the question as well as you can, rather than having multiple goes at it and potentially invalidating early answers.

A second option is to discuss the post in the site's [chat] room.  That way you can get some immediate feedback on a possible question.   This would also reduce the number of changes to a post.
Consider, the point of SE is the question and it's answers.

Ideally, in a perfect world, a question/answer would be fully formed and contain everything relevant when initially posted.  There would be no ambiguity or clarifications needed.   So - "zero edits" would be a pinnacle.  The closer any post gets to needing no-edits, the better it was prepared.

And yes, the last paragraph was added in an edit; I'm aware of the irony :)

It’s one thing to edit a little while afterwards where it you add something significant vs. minor edits that bump your posts to the main page at a rate of 4 per day.

@Criggie Technically, the last paragraph was not added in an edit, as you seemingly edited before the grace period.  Ain't no edits in your post's history. :D

@XanderHenderson it was an edit,we just can’t see it

@Starship Because explaining a joke always makes it funnier:  yes.  As I said, he edited it within the grace period.  So there is no edit in the history.  So, technically nothing was added in an edit.  That's the joke.

Joke's so bad they're layered.   But they don't get any better the deeper you dig.

It would be nice if the site had a proper multiple drafts system. Documentation had that and other enhancements that would have been nice on the rest of the site, but they never made it out.

@Jeremy that is legitimately a good idea for a feature-request.  I suggest you add it as a new question here on meta.SE

@Criggie I argued for it 12 years ago and it’s been brought by others both before and after that. Sadly it hasn’t happened. ☹️
